# How do I add newline to only dictionary values?

Tags: python

```
import pprint
def print_values(key):
    pprint.pprint(key, width=1)
```

I tried this, but it ends up printing both the keys and values. I only want the set to print the values, not the keys.

Comment: have you tried: `print(mydict.values())` (or `pprint.pprint(mydict.values())`)

Comment: I need the values printed with each values separated by new line characters.

Comment: `for v in key.values(): print(v)`

Comment: what are you passing to the `print_values` function when you call it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be...

```
import pprint
def print_values(key):
    pprint.pprint(dictionary[key], width=1)
```

To print only the keys / values of a dictionary do something like that:

```
dictionary = {'abc': 123, 'def': 456, 'ghi': 789}

# print the keys
for entry in dictionary:
    print(entry)

# print the values
for entry in dictionary:
    print(dictionary[entry])

# print the values
for entry in dictionary.values():
    print(entry)
```